# block changes in data validation if another cells says approved

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

Please help me. This is on Google Sheets

I have cell A1 B1 C1 and D1

A1 - manual input

B1 - drop down list using Data Validation

C1 - manual input

D1 - approval cell

What I want to happen is, **restrict** edit on A1 B1 C1 if D1="Approved"

While it is already doable for cells A1 and C1 using data validation custom formula,

How will I do it for cell B1?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here is the link for the sample file i made: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LXvMym0fhRveQwV-k-yyxf1kQGZVnpqISdxuRAuqs4Y/edit?usp=sharing